# Filtering out items from a list using nested list comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have two lists. One contains sentences, the other contains words.

I want to have all the sentences, which do NOT contain any of the words from the list of words.

I'm trying to achieve this with list comprehensions. Example:

```
cleared_sentences = [sentence for sentence in sentences if banned_word for word in words not in sentence]
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working as I get an error telling me that a variable is used before assignment.

I've tried looking for nested comprehensions and I am sure this must have been asked for but I can not find anything.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the order mixed up:

```
[sentence for sentence in sentences for word in words if banned_word not in sentence]
```

Not that that'll work as that'll list the `sentence` every time a banned word *does* show up in the sentence. Take a look at the fully expanded nested loops version:

```
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in words:
        if banned_word not in sentence:
            result.append(sentence)
```

Use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to test for banned words instead:

```
[sentence for sentence in sentences if not any(banned_word in sentence for banned_word in words)]
```

`any()` loops over the generator expression only until a `True` value is found; it'll stop doing work the moment a banned word is found in the sentence. This is more efficient at least.

Comment: I tried the list comprehension (the latter) and I still get an error. Is there any chance it might need to be .... any(banned_word in sentence for banned_word in words)?